# Page works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE but causes flashing or crash on iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I'm trying to create a content slider with jQuery and CSS3.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ngwyQ/87/) is my code. Page is working fine in Chrome, and is almost fine in Firefox, and it is functional in IE (but almost no effects).

But It is not working in iPad Safari...

When the page completes loading in iPad Safari, Page starts flashing (continuously, never finish) and then browser crashes!

But I can't find which part of [my slider](http://jsfiddle.net/ngwyQ/87/) has problem, and I don't know what the problem exactly is...

Sorry if my code is messy, but I couldn't find what the problem is, so I can't make a simpler example...

---

**Update**

My code has `window.resize` jQuery event and I'm calling `CorrectPages()` Inside it.

I have put this code on the first line of that event: `alert("windowResize" + window.innerWidth + " , " + window.innerHeight);`

In PC, there are no alerts until I resize the window. But in iPad, alerts began after page loads. These are the messages on iPad:

```
windowResize1767 , 1074
windowResise1767 , 2078
windowResize2099 , 4136
windowResize2099 , 8355
windowResize2099 , 17004
windowResize2099 , 34735
...
```

---

**Update 2**

As ahmadali said, now we fixed previous problem. [This is my fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/ngwyQ/101). But now, there is another problem: When page loads, Safari tells a wrong `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

When the page loads, it looks correct for a moment, but then, it changes. this is the result after a moment:
[image]

What's your idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mahdi,

I can't spot anything obvious but efficiency may be an issue. A shipload of improvements are possible.

Here are some general pointers:

- Put globals `beginX`, `beginY` etc. inside the `$(document).ready(function(){...})` closure.
- Minimise the need to find DOM nodes - cache jQuery objects and and use method chaining where possible.
- .removeclass() will remove multiple space separated classes. No need for separate statements
- `$("#d_page" + i + " #overlay")` is worrying. ids should be unique so why not `$("#overlay")` or `$(".... .overlay")`?
- Let jQuery methods `.eq()` and `.not()` do some of the hard work.
- Give the pages class="page". Let `$pages = $(".page")`, then `$("#d_page" + i.toString())` should simplify to `$pages.eq(i)`. Many expressions of this type will simplify.

By progressive improvement, I managed to reduce function `correctPages()` down from some 170+ lines down to just 26 lines.

This is what I ended up with :

```
function correctPages() {
    var $pages = $(".page"),//relies on pages having class="page"
        prefix = (isLandscape(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)) ? 'd_landscape_activepage_' : 'd_portrait_activepage_',
        classes = ["whitebackground", prefix+"1", prefix+"2", prefix+"3", prefix+"4"].join(' '),
        $np = [$pages.eq(currentPage), $pages.eq(nextPage(currentPage)), $pages.eq(nextPage(nextPage(currentPage))), $pages.eq(nextPage(nextPage(nextPage(currentPage))))];
    $pages.removeClass(classes);
    $pages.find(".overlay").css({top:0, opacity: 0.6});//relies on overlays having class="overlay"
    $pages.not($np[0]).not($np[1]).not($np[2]).addClass(prefix+"1");
    $pages.not($np[2]).removeClass(prefix+"5").addClass("transition");
    $pages.eq(prevPage(currentPage)).addClass(prefix+"2");
    $np[0].addClass(prefix+"3").find(".overlay").css("opacity", "0.1");
    $np[1].addClass(prefix+"4");
    $np[2].addClass(prefix+"5");
    $np[isNext ? 2 : 3].removeClass("transition");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $np[2].addClass("transition");
    }, 100);
    $(".articlecontent").css("background", "rgba(250,250,250,0)");
    $(".d_landscape_activepage_3 .articlecontent").css("background", "rgba(250,250,250,1)");
    $(".d_portrait_activepage_3 .articlecontent").css("background", "rgba(250,250,250,1)");
    correctDivs();
    $("#d_pagefix").css("opacity", "0");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $np[0].find(".overlay").css("top", "10000px");
    }, 400);
}
```

This code is untested so may not be 100% correct, but should give you some clues as to how it can be improved.

## Edit

As a workaround to the persistent re-triggering of the resize event, try detaching and re-attaching the resize handler dynamically.

Replace :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    correctPages();
});
```

with ;

```
function attachResizeHandler() {
    $(window).on('resize', resizeHandler);
}
function resizeHandler() {
    $(window).off('resize');
    correctPages();
    setTimeout(attachResizeHandler, 600);
}
```

I chose 600 ms as it's slightly longer than the longest timeout in the correctPages or checkhash code. You may get away with less depending on exactly what triggers the unwanted resize event.

Elsewhere in the code, replace all instances of :

```
`correctPages();`
```

with :

```
`resizeHandler();`
```

Initial attachment of `resizeHandler` will then occur when `checkhash();` is called on page load.

Comment: So you think that that huge javascript may cause safari to crash?

Comment: I haven't iPad myself (My friend tested my code), and he now tells that the problem is not after swiping! it is from when page completes loading!

Comment: Mahdi, my suggestions are chiefly for runtime efficiency - primarily by performing far fewer interactions with the DOM. Reduction in volume of code is a bonus. I too have no iPad, but it's interesting that the problem should occur after loading. See if you can do similar improvements in that part of the code.

Comment: In response to your research with @ahmadali, I have edited my answer above to add a possible workaround.

Comment: If I add `viewport` meta tag, then current problem may fixed. And if so, I can detect orientation change with jQuery Mobile events. But if they don't help me, then your suggested workaround will be the best way, I think. And just for knowledge: Browser crash problem was just from not-optimized code! Now my code is much more optimized and browser is not crashing! So, **thank you, because you told that optimization is much important... :)**

Comment: Mahdi, I just looked at your revised code and it is dramatically improved! You are clearly a quick learner.

Answer (score 2):

Well, me and Mahdi tested the code a lot with iPad and finally we understood that the problem is from `JqueryMobile`. I had this code

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>'+$(window).height()+","+$(window).width());
});​
```

and when I run it without adding a reference to `JqueryMobile` in iPad the page doesn't change and nothing added to the page [(code)](http://jsfiddle.net/pV3Za/1/).

But when I run it with adding a reference to `JqueryMobile` in iPad it always added new page sizes [(code)](http://jsfiddle.net/pV3Za/2/).

I think it's a really important bug of `JqueryMobile` for multi platform web programmers. and I reported it [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4857).

Comment: Ahmadali, good analysis, +1. See my edited answer for a possible workaround.

Comment: Jquery or JQuery is wrong. **jQuery** is the correct spelling... Also, there should be a space between `jQuery` and `Mobile`.